# Spring Boot Actuator endpoints not showing property values when read from K8s configmap

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, kubernetes, spring-boot-actuator, configmap

I am trying to view some custom properties that I have in a projects `application.yml`.

```
meanwhileinhell:
  myproject:
    myserver:
      security:
        users:
          - username: user1
            password: "{noop}password1"
            roles:
              - USER
          - username: user2
            password: "{noop}password2"
            roles:
              - USER
      services:
        - "service-the-first"
        - "another-service"
```

I run my system in a Kubernetes cluster, and during my installation I create `configmap`s of each of my projects `application.yml`, with the command:

```
kubectl create configmap <project> --from-file "<project>/src/main/resources/application.yml"
```

Viewing these configmaps on my running system, I can see that all the values are there.

These properties bind to a Kotlin classes:

```
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties("meanwhileinhell.myproject.myserver.security")
class SecurityUsersProperties(val users: List<User>)

data class User(val username: String, val password: String, val roles: List<String>)
```

```
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties("meanwhileinhell.myproject.myserver")
class ServiceNameProperties(val services: List<String>)
```

which are then enabled in a couple of config classes:

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ServiceNameProperties::class)
```

> Note! The `SecurityUsersProperties::class` is enabled on
> `WebSecurityConfig` class.

These values are all loaded successfully, as I can use the credentials to log in where needed, and monitor that specific list of services.

My issue is when I try to view the properties on the `actuator/configprops` endpoint.  I can see the list of property names, but when I click to expand the values they are not displayed.

```
contexts:
  application-1:
    beans:
      meanwhileinhell.myproject.myserver.security-com.meanwhileinhell.myproject.myserver.security.properties.SecurityUsersProperties:
        properties:
          users:
        inputs:
          users:
            0:
              roles:
                0:
                  origin:    "\"meanwhileinhell.myproject.myserver.security.users[0].roles[0]\" from property source \"bootstrapProperties-configmap.myserver.default\""
            1:
              roles:
                0:
                  origin:    "\"meanwhileinhell.myproject.myserver.security.users[1].roles[0]\" from property source \"bootstrapProperties-configmap.myserver.default\""
```

In this instance, only `roles:` are shown, no `username` or (sanitised) `password`.  The same is true if I search for my list of services:

```
contexts:
  application-1:
    beans:
      meanwhileinhell.myproject.myserver.services-com.meanwhileinhell.myproject.myserver.health.properties.ServiceNameProperties:
        properties:
          services:
        inputs:
          services:
            0:
              origin:   "\"meanwhileinhell.myproject.myserver.services[0]\" from property source \"bootstrapProperties-configmap.myserver.default\""
            1:
              origin:   "\"meanwhileinhell.myproject.myserver.services[1]\" from property source \"bootstrapProperties-configmap.myserver.default\""
```

In my root `build.gradle.kts`, I have enabled the actuator endpoints on all services:

```
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
```

Is there something I'm missing that is allowing my properties to be displayed?

**Update**
My `env` actuator endpoint seems to be working now, and displaying my username and (sanitized) passwords as well as the role.  But, `configprops` still is not displaying them, only the `roles` like mentioned above.

Comment: Does the `actuator/env` endpoint contain the expected properties?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson No, `env` has the same issue

Comment: That sounds like Spring Boot isn't picking up the configuration at all. How have you configured your application to consume the config maps that you've set up in Kubernetes?

Comment: Yeah, the application do seem to pick up the configs.  I can log in using the users, if I update the configmaps, it picks up the new values etc.  I'm wondering if it could it be something to do with the use of Kotlin data classes?

Comment: As a suggestion, have you tried to debug the actual endpoint? It has a pretty easy-to-follow source code - maybe it will shed some light on the issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/context/properties/ConfigurationPropertiesReportEndpoint.java

Comment: @MarkBramnik No, I haven't, I will give that a go.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I've added an update to my question, seem to have `env` showing correct properties, but not `configprops`.